# How to control a Bluetooth LE connection on Windows 10?

Tags: c#, windows, bluetooth

I need to develop an application which communicates with a device via bluetooth low energy. Once the application is connected to the device via bluetooth it receives and sends data by using a gatt service.

The application needs to run on a Windows 10 environment. So far I was able to develop and try the application by using the following UWP classes:

[DeviceWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceWatcher);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)

[BluetoothLEDevice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.BluetoothLEDevice);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)

Once the device has been discovered and paired the communication starts. The main problem I have is that I am not able to control the connection/disconnection with the device, that is the connection starts automatically once the device has been properly and previously paired, but I haven't found any connect()/disconnect() method so far.

Is there a way to control the connection with a specific bluetooth LE device? Are there other APIs which allow to use the bluetooth without using the UWP framework and which offer more control over the bluetooth?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once the device is paired, whenever it turns on close to the Windows 10 machine, it will try to connect. This is defined behavior in Bluetooth, as the peripheral will always send out a connection request when it is turned on.

There is a DeviceWatcher background task that you can register for to trigger your app when your Bluetooth device connects. You can find [some sample code here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing/cs/Scenario3_BackgroundDeviceWatcher.xaml.cs).

**Is there a way to control the connection with a specific bluetooth LE device?**

Yes. To initiate a connection: when you create a `BluetoothLEDevice` via `FromBluetoothAddressAsync` or `FromIdAsync` the system will try to initiate a connection to that peripheral, if it does not already hold a connection.

```
// Connects to a Bluetooth device, given some string deviceId
BluetoothLEDevice bleDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceId);
```

To dispose of a connection, call the `close` method on `BluetoothLEDevice`. If your app is the only entity with a handle to the peripheral, this will cause the system to disconnect. However, if another app or system service has a handle to the peripheral, the connection will not be closed.

```
// Will disconnect from the BTLE device, if you hold the only handle
bleDevice.close()
```

These are taken from the [BluetoothLEDevice documentation here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothledevice)

**Are there other APIs?**

There are not any other APIs built in to Windows 10 that offer more control over Bluetooth. The UWP APIs offer the most control that Windows 10 currently provides. You could use an alternate Bluetooth stack, but these would have to be installed separately and likely break other Bluetooth behavior on Windows 10.

Comment: What if I have a list of `deviceId` and I need to connect to each one of them, one after the other, in an endless loop? Should I create the `BluetoothLEDevice`, get its services, send and transmit data, and finally close the device, before moving to the next one? Will I have problems connecting to each device in this way? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why would you want to close the connection if you're just going to open it back up a bit later? Can you describe what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Is it possible to keep the connection with multiple devices at the same time? I need to send and receive data to/from all of these devices.

Comment: Yes, you can maintain a connection with multiple devices at once, but there is a limit depending on your host's radio hardware (on some hosts it may be as low as 7).

Comment: Sometimes it works, sometimes doesn't. You don't really have contro over the connection. A very bad implementation of Microsoft.

Comment: Is the fact that when you call "FromIdAsync" Windows tries to connect to the device documented somewhere? Because I do it for all devices and I have never seen it connected to any of them automatically.